# file not found exception when trying to create jar file

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I have the following Java file(apples.java):

```
public class apples
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       System.out.println("Apples here.");
    }
}
```

saved in the `source` folder of the `MyProject` directory.

I compile apples.java and save the apples.class file into the `classes` folder of the `MyProject` directory.

I then create manifest.txt with the following content:

```
Main-Class: apples
```

I then navigate into the MyProject/classes directory via cmd prompt(Windows XP) and type the following command:

```
jar -cvmf manifest.txt app1.jar apples.class
```

I get the following message in the command prompt:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: manifest.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)

           at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
```

What is wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: `manifest.txt` inside jar its not `File`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the .jar argument first

`jar -cvmf app1.jar  manifest.txt apples.class`

Make sure both "apples.class" and "manifest.jar" are in the current directory.

I would also encourage you to:

1) Use packages (instead of the default package)

2) Capitalize your class names ("Apples.java" instead of "apples")

Here's a nice, short tutorial that might help:

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-add-your-manifest-into-a-jar-file/

Answer (score 1):

It is a common mistake people make. While creating the manifest.txt, make sure that you don't name it "manifest.txt", after you've already selected the file to be a txt. That makes it "manifest.txt.txt". Hope it helps.